# using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution

Tags: tensorflow

I'm writing a neural network and I have a "using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution" error that I cant't fix when I call compile. I have written my own custom loss, which I think is what throws the error.

```
def compute_loss(Z5, Z6, C, YC, YI, YL):
  cost1 = np.add(np.matmul(-(Z5), YI), np.log(np.add(1, np.exp(Z5))))
  cost1 = np.add(Z6, np.add(-np.dot(Z6, YL), np.log(np.add(1, exp(-Z6)))))
  cost2 = np.add(Z5, np.add(-np.dot(Z5, YI), np.log(np.add(1, exp(-Z5)))))
  cost1 = np.add(C, np.add(-np.dot(C, YC), np.log(np.add(1, exp(-YC)))))

  return cost

d2, D2I, D2L, C = d2(images) #call function to build network
custom_loss = compute_loss(D2I, D2L, C, y_c, y_i, y_l)
my_metric = tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(name="accuracy", dtype=None)

d2.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=custom_loss, metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()], run_eagerly=True)
```

I have tried converting D2I, D2L, C to arrays using either numpy() or nd_array() but they both throw tensorflow error. any help would be appreciated
Also tried changing the loss to

```
def compute_loss(Z5, Z6, C, YC, YI, YL):
  cost1 = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=Z5, labels=YI)
  cost2 = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=Z6, labels=YL)
  cost3 = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=C, labels=YC)
  cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.add(cost1, tf.add(cost2, cost3)))
  return cost
```

but that threw same error

Comment: Which line of code gives this error, or could you give more error logs?

Comment: The error is thrown at d2.compile when I use nn.softmax version of the loss. My attempt to fix it was to add 'run_eagerly=True in compile (as I have checked and i am executing in eager ) but it does not change anything. So my second attempt was to write my own softmax cross entropy using numpy add and mamtul (first version of loss you see in my code), byt that throws an 'array() takes one positional argument but two wre given' error